# US Green card holder with Indian passport expiring in 4 months planning a short weekend trip by road to Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, us-residents

I am a US Green card holder with an Indian passport expiring in 4 months planning a short weekend trip by road to Canada next month.

Will I be allowed to enter Canada considering my passport won't meet the "valid passport" criteria of 6 months?

Comment: Do you have a reference supporting your assumption that there is a 6-month criterion?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a passport at all to enter Canada by land, only your Green card.

As such, the question is moot.

Answer (score 5):

Canada has no 6-month valid passport criterion.  I just looked into this last week as I'm planning a trip to Canada in two weeks with someone whose passport expires in September.

I have no reference for this except to say that the six-month requirement is to be found nowhere at any of the following pages:

- https://travel.gc.ca/returning/travelling-to-canada.
- https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ivc-rnc-eng.html
- https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html

As to your return in the US, [you don't need a passport at all](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents), much less a passport meeting any sort of minimum validity requirement.

Comment: OP doesn't Need a passport to enter Canada by land either

Comment: @Coke good point.  I must have overlooked "road trip."