# I am traveling to Canada on a visitor visa on my old passport. and I have a new one

Tags: canada

I have a visitor visa to Canada on my old passport. I renewed my passport to have. six months valid passport when travelling. can I enter Canada with a visa on my old passport? I will take both passports with me?

and do I really need a six months valid passport when entering Canada?

Comment: Travel on your new passport and have the visa in the old passport ready to show to the officer. This quite common and the officer will be ok with it - provided the visa is still valid and you're using it for the purpose for which it was granted.

Answer (score 3):

> can I Enter Canada with a visa on my old passport?

Yes, as long as the visa remains valid.  (Canadian visas are not normally valid beyond the passport's expiration date.)  See [Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87429/19400)

> I will take both passports with me?

Yes.  If you don't bring both passports, you won't have the visa.

> and do I really need a six months valid passport when entering canada?

No.  Canada requires only that the passport be valid for the duration of your stay.  If you show up with a passport that is valid for a period shorter than six months, you will be admitted until the day on which your passport expires.  See [Passport validity for Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/118289/19400).