# Passport Validity to cross Border to Canada

Tags: canada

I am going to be driving across the border from Seattle to Canada in August with my grand children ages 13 and 15.  Their parents will not be with us and the children's passports expire in January.  Will we have any problems crossing the border?

Comment: Are they US citizens? Will you have a consent letter from the parents? http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html

Answer (score 2):

Canada requires passports to be valid for the duration of a visitor's stay.  There is [no requirement for additional validity](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/118289/19400).

You could bring a notarized letter from the children's parents permitting you to travel with them.  It's unlikely to be necessary, but if anyone does decide that something untoward is going on, the letter should help dispel their suspicions.